# android-wear watch: set time to next update?

Tags: android-studio, timer, wear-os

I'm working on a balanced ternary watch face.

How can I set the time to the next update?

I'd like to update in the middle of every second, minute, hour and night.
Or during conservation mode, only the middle over every minute, hour and night.

The best way to do this would be to find tell the system not to redraw until the desired time has elapsed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different answers to different parts of your question.

While the watch is awake, you are free to update the face whenever you want, at whatever interval you want. Google's [analog watch face sample](https://developer.android.com/samples/WatchFace/Wearable/src/com.example.android.wearable.watchface/AnalogWatchFaceService.html) updates once per second, and that's a fine starting point. You'll just want to modify `mUpdateTimeHandler` with an offset of 500ms, and then do additional checks to determine if you're in the middle of a minute, hour or night.

When in ambient mode, `WatchFaceService` has an `onTimeTick()` method - but that fires when the minute changes, not "in the middle" of each minute. My guess is you'll ignore `onTimeTick()` and roll your own code, using `AlarmManager` with an offset to fire in the middle of each minute to do your updates.

Comment: Thank you. AlarmManager seems to be the tool that I was missing most.